# How to refer http handler file from jQuery ajax under different directory of asp.net web application

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a http handler file in following directory of my application

[image]

I am referring this handler from `common.js` file using jQuery ajax and  `common.js` file referred in aspx pages `StoresSummary.aspx` & `EmployeeProfile.aspx`

From `EmployeeProfile.aspx` I am able to call the handler and getting the output, but from `StoresSummary.aspx` jquery ajax call getting failed.

I know the cause of failure because the path of `CommonHandler.ashx` file does not map correctly due to location hierarchy of `StoresSummary.aspx`.

This is a sample code I am posting, the http handler file I need to call from Jquery ajax and aspx pages may exists in different directory of same web application.

I need to how do I give path of `CommonHandler.ashx` in ajax jQuery call so any location hierarchy of my aspx page can call it.

This is my code

**common.js**

```
function GetMessage(key) {
var message = '';

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../../Common/Handlers/CommonHandler.ashx', /*Working for EmoloyeeProfile.aspx but not for StoresSummary.aspx*/
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'MessageKey': key },
    success: onSucess,
    error: OnFailed,
    async: false
});

function onSucess(res) {
    message = res;
}

function OnFailed(res) {
    alert('failed');
}

return message;
}
```

**StoresSummary.aspx**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="../../../Common/Scripts/common.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../Common/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Get Message" OnClientClick="return CallMethod();" />
    </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
         function CallMethod() {
             var msg = GetMessage('001');            
             alert(msg);
             return false;
         }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**EmployeeProfile.aspx**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="../Common/Scripts/common.js"></script>
    <script src="../Common/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Get Message" OnClientClick="return CallMethod();" />
    </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CallMethod() {
            var msg = GetMessage('001');
            alert(msg);
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CommonHandler.ashx**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace DemoWebApp.Common.Handlers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for CommonHandler
    /// </summary>
    public class CommonHandler : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string result = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(GetData(context.Request["MessageKey"]));
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            context.Response.Write(result);
        }

        private string GetData(string Id)
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToString(); //just to demostrate
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of relative path (**../../Common/Handlers/CommonHandler.ashx**), you can start your path from root(**/Common/Handlers/CommonHandler.ashx**). So it will work for any page:

```
function GetMessage(key) {
var message = '';

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Common/Handlers/CommonHandler.ashx', /*Working for EmoloyeeProfile.aspx but not for StoresSummary.aspx*/
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'MessageKey': key },
    success: onSucess,
    error: OnFailed,
    async: false
});

function onSucess(res) {
    message = res;
}

function OnFailed(res) {
    alert('failed');
}

return message;
}
```